# whats the rule for the statements?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I cant seem to find the formula for this series of statements. If it was a sequence on the lhs i would be ok but it is a product and i cant see a way to get a formula for that any help would be appreciated, thanks.

$(1-1/2)=1/2$

$(1-1/2)(1-1/3)=1/3$

$(1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/4)=1/4$

Comment: One formula is $\prod\limits_{k=2}^n \left( 1-\frac1k \right)$

Comment: Do you mean what the pattern is? If so, essentially, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\prod_{n=2}^k \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: actually wait a second whats that symbol

Comment: @EeveeTrainer You product is always $0$.

Comment: @callculus Fixed that, thanks.

Comment: @peterjohn The big pi symbol is to products basically what the big sigma is for sums. Basically it means an iterative product. For example:

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 k = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5$$

is an iterative sum, where

$$\prod_{k=1}^5 k = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5$$

is an iterative product.

Comment: Oh thanks, never came across that before

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thanks for the reply

Comment: Can you treat that symbol like a sigma symbol? Do the same rules apply?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: sorry ignore that comment i will look up that symbol. Why do i have a negative 1

Comment: "Can you treat that symbol like a sigma symbol?"  I sigma symbol $\Sigma_{i=1}^k a_i$ means you add up $a_1$ to $a_k$.  And $\prod_{i=1}^k a_i$ means you multiply $a_1$ to $a_k$.  So they are "like" except one is for adding and the other is for multiplying. "Do the same rules apply?" Depends.  What rules?  $\sigma$ follows the rules for adding and $\prod$ would follow the rules for multiplying.  Example $\sum c*a_i = c\sum a_i$ because $(ca_1+... +ca_k) = c(a_1+...+a_k)$.  But $\prod c*a_i = c^k\prod a_i$ because $ca_1\cdot ca_2...\cdot ca_k = c^k(a_1a_2.....a_k)$.  They aren't the same .cont.

Comment: They aren't the same when the rules for addition and subtraction aren't the same but they are the same when they are.  Example if $a_0 a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = a_3 + a_2 + a_1+a_0$  and $a_0a_1a_2a_3=a_3a_2a_1a_0$ so $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i = \sum_{i=0}^k a_{k-i}$ and $\prod_{i=0}^k a_i = \prod_{i=0}^k a_{k-i}$ so those rules are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you are asking.  Statements don't have "formulas".  Statements merely are statements that, if correct, are true.

It is true that those statements are true. And they can each be verified directly.

This strongly implies that, in general, that

$(1-\frac 12)(1-\frac 13)(1-\frac 14)...... (1 - \frac 1n) = \frac 1n$.

Is that true? And can we prove/verify it?

Well.  For any $k$ we know $1 - \frac 1k = \frac kk - \frac 1k = \frac {k-1}k$.

So

$(1-\frac 12)(1-\frac 13)(1-\frac 14)...... (1 - \frac 1n) =$

$\frac 12\frac 23\frac 34..... \frac {n-2}{n-1}\frac {n-1}{n}$.

And by cross canceling:

$\require{cancel}$

$(1-\frac 12)(1-\frac 13)(1-\frac 14)...... (1 - \frac 1n) =$

$\frac 1{\color{red}{\cancel 2}}\frac {\color{red}{\cancel 2}}{\color{green}{\cancel 3}}\frac {\color{green}{\cancel 3}}{\color{purple}{\cancel 4}}..... \frac {\color{orange}{\cancel {n-2}}} {\color{blue}{\cancel {n-1}}}\frac {\color{blue}{\cancel {n-1}}}{n}=\frac 1n$

This would be an *excellent* opportunity to hone up you proof by induction skills:

Base Case: $n = 2$;

$(1 - \frac 12) = \frac 12$.  That is true.

Induction step:

Assume $(1 - \frac 12)..... (1-\frac 1k) = \frac 1k$, prove that $(1-\frac 12) ..... (1-\frac 1{k+1}) = \frac 1{k+1}$.

Pf: $(1 - \frac 12)..... (1-\frac 1k)(1 - \frac 1{k+1}) = $

$[(1 - \frac 12)..... (1-\frac 1k)](1 - \frac 1{k+1}) = $

$\frac 1k (1- \frac 1{k+1}) =$

$\frac 1k(\frac {k+1}{k+1} - \frac 1{k+1}) =$

$\frac 1k(\frac {(k+1) -1}{k+1}) =$

$\frac 1k(\frac k{k+1}) = $

$\frac 1{\cancel k}(\frac {\cancel k}{k+1}) = \frac 1{k+1}$.

So by induction: As the statement is true for $n =2$ and whenever the statement is true for $n =k$ it is also true for $n=k+1$ then by induction it must be true for all natural numbers $n \ge 2$

====

By the way the ideas that:

$\frac {a_1}{a_2}\cdot \frac {a_2}{a_3}\cdot.... \cdot {a_{n-1}}{a_{n}} =$

$\frac {a_1}{\cancel{a_2}}\cdot \frac {\cancel{a_2}}{\cancel{a_3}}\cdot.... \cdot \frac{\cancel{a_{n-1}}}{a_{n}} =\frac {a_1}{a_n}$

ANd $(a_1 - a_2) + (a_2 - a_3) + (a_3 - a_4) + .... + (a_{n-1} - a_n) =$

$a_1 +(-a_2 + a_2) +(-a_3 + a_3) + ..... +(-a_{n-1} + a_{n-1}) - a_{n} =$

$a_1 + 0 + 0 + ..... + 0 - a_n=$

$a_1 - a_n$

are called *telescoping* sums/products because the collapse like a telescope.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to prove is that $$\prod_{n=2}^k{\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)}=\frac{1}{k}$$
Am I right? This can be proven by induction:

Assume that for some $k$ (here 2)$$\prod_{n=2}^k{\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)}=\frac{1}{k}$$
(Inductive step) Now for $k+1$:
$$\prod_{n=2}^{k+1}{\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)}=\prod_{n=2}^k{\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)}*\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\Bigl)=\Bigl(\frac{1}{k}\Bigl)\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\Bigl)$$
$$=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k+1}{k(k+1)}-\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Since it works for $k=2$ it works $\forall{k}\in{\mathbb{N}}$